# Powershell v2 and SQL

Tags: sql-server, powershell-2.0

running the query found below in powershell v2 I get error:

> "Get-WmiObject : Invalid query 
>       At line:1 char:10
>       + $r = gwmi <<<<  -query $q -ComputerName $cname -Namespace $ns
>           + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand"

```
$q = @"
SELECT DISTINCT R.ID, 
       R.Type, 
       R.Name, 
       R.Client
FROM R_Table R,
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT G.ID FROM G_Table AS G WHERE Name LIKE "Microsoft Windows 7%") Win7
  on R.Id = Win7.ID
"@
$r = gwmi -query $q -ComputerName $cname -Namespace $ns
```

But, if I change `(SELECT DISTINCT G.ID FROM G_Table AS G WHERE Name LIKE "Microsoft Windows 7%")`
to be a Table instead of a selection it works fine?

Thanks

Comment: What is `$ns` set to? Are you attempting to query a SQL Server database via WMI?

Comment: $ns is the site code for my sccm server, sits value is:

Comment: $ns = "root/sms/siteXXX"

Comment: I wasn't aware, but I guess sccm uses SQL server in the background, our version is SQL Server 2008.